# Protecting against XSS when displayed using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xss, htmlspecialchars

`data` returned from the server is susceptible to XSS.  Do I need to sanitize the data at the server before sending it to the client using something like `htmlspecialchar()`, or does `$.get()` midigate the XSS?  Thank you

```
$.get('getData.php',
function (data){
    $('#div1').text(data.div1);
    $('#div2').html(data.div2);
    $('#textarea').val(data.textarea);
},'json');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#div1').text(data.div1);
```

This is not suceptible to XSS since you're changing the *text* of the element. This takes care of what you use `htmlspecialchars` for.

```
$('#div2').html(data.div2);
```

This is, since you're changing the *html* and not the text, so if you don't know your response someone could put a `<script>` tag there and run arbitrary code on your page.

```
$('#textarea').val(data.textarea);
```

Is also ok, since it changes the content of a text area.

Comment: Thank you Benjamin.  To ensure that I understand, I should use `htmlspecialchars()` on `.html()`, but need not on the other two.

Comment: You would not use `.html` to begin with with content you do not completely trust. I strongly suggest you store the _templates_ on the client side and pass the _data_ from the server, then use something like Mustache to render those templates (Mustache escapes HTML chars by default)